# Firebase security "read" rule work only in simulator

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm creating an android app using firebase.  My database structure is like this,

```
user:{
     $uid:{
           uname: abc,
           age: 20,
           email: abc@gmail.com,
           premium: true,
           score: 80
           }
       }
```

And security rules look like this,

```
  {
   "rules": {
           "user":{

                 "$uid":{
                        "score":{
                              ".read":"auth.uid===$uid",
                              ".write":"auth.uid===$uid"
                               },
                        "$others":{
                                ".read":"auth!=null",
                                ".write":"auth!=null"
                                }
                       }
                   }
             }
    }
```

And this is the code I read data from firebase,

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                               .child("user").child(uid);

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           users = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            //set values to associated textviews
        }

         @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

  });
```

The problem is ".read" rule only in simulator, although ".write" rule work in both app and simulator. When I change the rule to this,

```
  {
   "rules": {
           "user":{
                 "$uid":{
                          ".read":"auth!=null",
                          ".write":"auth!=null",
                        "score":{
                              ".read":"auth.uid===$uid",
                              ".write":"auth.uid===$uid"
                               },
                        "$others":{
                                ".read":"auth!=null",
                                ".write":"auth!=null"
                                }
                       }
                   }
             }
    }
```

Its work for both read and write.But this is not secure. Why can't I read data even auth.uid = myUid? However ".write" rule always goes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first solution nobody can read `/users/$uid`, so it makes sense your listeners gets rejected.

To make it work, you'll need to grant the user who can read all data access to `/users/$uid`. As far as I can see:

1. A user can read their own entire node.
2. All authenticated users can read the all but the score of a user.

The closest you can get to that is:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "user": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth.uid===$uid",
                ".write": "auth.uid===$uid"
                "score": {
                },
                "$others": {
                    ".read": "auth!=null",
                    ".write": "auth!=null"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these rules:

1. Each user can read their entire node.
2. All authenticate users can read each specific property of each other user, but not their score.

So each authentication user can read `/users/anyUid/foo` and `/users/anyUid/bar`, but not `/users/anyUid/score`.

---

The tricky bit here is that users can still not read `/users/anyUid` of any user. The reason for this is that permission cascades: once you can read a node, you can read all data under that node. So once you grant anyone read permission on `/users/$uid`, you can't remove that permission at a lower level.

For this reason you'll typically want to store data that requires separate access permission into separate top-level nodes. If we rewrite your rules a bit, we get to:

- All authenticated users can read all user profiles.
- An authenticated user can only read/write their own score.

That'd translate into this data structure:

```
profiles: {
  uid1: { ... },
  uid2: { ... }
},
scores: {
  uid1: ...,
  uid2: ...
}
```

And now you can easily secure it with:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "profiles": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth!=null",
                ".write": "auth!=null"
            }
        },
        "score": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth.uid===$uid",
                ".write": "auth.uid===$uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first opinion doesn't work either, because actually there is another "premium" node which is "false" for both read and write. First way allows user to read all child nodes. Is there some ways to try (rule for each child node)? If no way , I'll try second opinion.